# Jquery add/remove automaticly

Tags: jquery

I would like to add / remove value automatically for my example:

```
$('#select_factu').on('change', function () {
        if (this.value == 'Mois'){
            $('{!! Form::date('date_facturation', Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMonth(1),['class' => 'form-control']) !!}').appendTo('.ajout_factu');
        } else if (this.value == 'Annuel'){
            $('{!! Form::date('date_facturation', Carbon\Carbon::now()->addYear(1),['class' => 'form-control']) !!}').appendTo('.ajout_factu');
        }
    });
```

This method works but adds fields without deleting the previous one.

How can I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you clear your container div, you will add always one,

```
$('.ajout_factu').empty();

$('#select_factu').on('change', function () {
        $('.ajout_factu').empty();
        if (this.value == 'Mois'){
            $('{!! Form::date('date_facturation', Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMonth(1),['class' => 'form-control']) !!}').appendTo('.ajout_factu');
        } else if (this.value == 'Annuel'){
            $('{!! Form::date('date_facturation', Carbon\Carbon::now()->addYear(1),['class' => 'form-control']) !!}').appendTo('.ajout_factu');
        }
    });
```